# Entity framework where column is equal nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following query

```
 var maListe = (from p in db.full
                       where ((p.acknowledge_by.Equals(..) && date>(new DateTime(2015,03,03)))

                       select new RequeteOptimise
                       {
                           objet = p.mc_object
                       }).ToList();
```

Inside (...) i need to put something that doesnt effect of query, the result should be like if we run this query

```
 var maListe = (from p in db.full
                       where ( date>(new DateTime(2015,03,03))

                       select new RequeteOptimise
                       {
                           objet = p.mc_object
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*nothing*"? `String.Empty`, `null`,... ? What is the type of the `p.acknowledge_by` field?

Comment: it's string, nothing means something that wont affect results, the result would be the same if we remove the p.acknowledge_by condition

Comment: sorry, I might be confused, but are you asking for a way to provide a criteria for the `Equals()` that means "All Values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this up:

```
var queryBase = db.full.Where(p => date > (new DateTime(2015,03,03))).AsQueryAble();
```

Then if you have to (inside an if block for example)

```
queryBase = queryBase.Where(p => p.acknowledge_by.Equals( yourcriteria ));
```

And then materialize:

```
var maListe = queryBase.Select(p => new RequeteOptimise{ objet = p.mc_object }).ToList();
```

Alternative in one Swing:

```
var maListe = (from p in db.full
               where ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourcritera) || p.acknowledge_by.Equals(yourcriteria)) && date > new DateTime(2015,03,03)
               select new RequeteOptimise
               {
                   objet = p.mc_object
               }).ToList();
```